# Create build flavor in ReactJS create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

recently I've been trying to create different build flavor *(e.g PRO or ADVANCE or LITE)* of apps for each of my clients. Do any of you have any hint of how to create configurations for build process so it only include modules based on settings?

*(e.g. for client A i want to only include component A, B, C. For client D only include component B AND D. etc.)*

I've been trying to search some clue these past days. Yet, I only got information that can be used for React-native (I'm using ReactJS with Create react app)

Your help is very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Custom Environment Variables](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables) in Create react app. For example:

```
REACT_APP_YOUR_CUSTOM=PRO
```

And then in your code, you can check it:

```
if (process.env.REACT_APP_YOUR_CUSTOM === 'PRO') {
   //render A,B,C
} else if (process.env.REACT_APP_YOUR_CUSTOM === 'LITE') {
    //render D
} else {
    //render B
}
```

Note: You always need to prefix REACT_APP_ to the variable name.

Comment: Thank you max for giving me the hint/answer :)